# Oracle PL/SQL : Replicating Database objects

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, materialized-views

I need replicate database objects from one database to another database. 
For tables I can do it by

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_USERS AS SELECT * FROM TBL_USERS@DBLINK;
```

which will copy both the table structure and data.

Is there similar way to copy Materialized Views with its underlying SQL codes and procedures/packages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ongoing, will the MVs continue to be populated from the original database (@DBLINK) or from tables in the new (target) database?

Comment: Just as a sidenote, `create table x as select * from y` does not replicate constraints, triggers, indexes etc. on that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to this is: No, you cannot replicate PL/SQL procedure, views, trigger, tables, etc. via PL/SQL.

There might be tricks around some of this but not everything will replicated. What you describe above is a simple DDL using a [Database Link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/ds_concepts.htm#ADMIN12083) to replicate data. It's not PL/SQL as such and it only replicates the table structure and data set itself. No constraints, indexes, trigger nor any security properties such as grants are replicated. There are several ways in Oracle to replicate database objects across multiple databases, one of them being [Data Pump Export](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/dp_export.htm#i1007466) and [Data Pump Import](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/dp_import.htm#SUTIL300):

**Source DB "GV11202"**

```
SQL> select directory_path from all_directories where directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';

DIRECTORY_PATH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/u01/app/oracle/admin/GV11202/dpdump/

bash$ expdp system/system@GV11202 DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=export.dmp SCHEMAS=test
```

**Target DB "GVENZL"**

```
SQL> select directory_path from all_directories where directory_name = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';

DIRECTORY_PATH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/u01/app/oracle/admin/GVENZL/dpdump/

bash$ cp /u01/app/oracle/admin/GV11202/dpdump/export.dmp /u01/app/oracle/admin/GVENZL/dpdump/

bash$ impdp system/system@GVENZL DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=export.dmp
```

Import dump file - as there is only the test schema within the dump file, I can just plainly import the schema with all its objects. However, if you import into an existing schema where tables might already exist, have a look at the [TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/dp_import.htm#SUTIL936)